# How to get iOS 10.3.2(14F89)

Tags: ios, iphone

I need run my Project with Xcode7,but my iPhone iOS Version is 10.3.2(14F89),How to get iOS10.3.2(14F89) Device support files??

Answer (score 1):

you should update your Xcode to Xcode8,and it support your device.

Comment: But I do't want to upgrade

Comment: you can download two Xcode,and use the newest Xcode to run your device.so you can not to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

- Close/Quit `Xcode 7` completely.
- Download `Xcode 8.3.3` from [Apple site](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/)

### Step one

- Right click on the downloaded .dmg file and show package contents
- Navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/`
- Copy the `SDKs` folder
- Go to older version of Xcode, e.g. `Xcode 7`, in the *Finder -> Applications -> Xcode*
- Right click and show package contents
- Navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/`
- Paste the copied `SDKs` folder here

### Step two

- Right click on the downloaded .dmg file and show package contents
- Navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`
- Copy the `10.3` folder
- Go to older version of Xcode, e.g. `Xcode 7`, in the *Finder -> Applications -> Xcode*
- Right click and show package contents
- Navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`
- Paste the copied `10.3` folder here

**Finally restart you old Xcode.**

Comment: OK ，I replace it，I try run ， some system header file ERROR

Comment: What's the version of your `mac OS`?

Comment: When do you experience ___system header file ERROR___? I mean, when you try to run your project in your iPhone or some other times?