# How to test apps for iOS 11 on an older xCode version than 9

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, xcode9

After updating my xCode to be version 9.0, I'm facing an issue with the custom navigationBar, the status bar and navigation bar are colliding which was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138245/how-to-change-navigationbar-height-in-ios-11/46138389?noredirect=1#comment79643281_46138389) as a bug from xCode...

My question is: how can build my project for iOS 11 too with an older version so I wouldn't have this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985307/

Comment: @Mats this question is basically the opposite of mine.. I need to build for iOS 11 not previous versions, but I want the custom NavigationBar issue solved too which comes with xCode 9.. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Try using an old XCode but changing its BaseSDK to that of a newer one.. Otherwise I don't think it's possible and you'll have to find a different workaround.

Comment: You will need to get your app working with Xcode 9 and iOS 11 eventually. You might at well get it working now instead of later.

Comment: @rmaddy that's true but the bug is from xCode so it's not a decision to get it working :/ thanks anyway, seems like I'll need to live with the bug for now

Comment: If there is is a bug, it's with iOS 11, not Xcode.

Comment: @KasemHato:  Are you facing navigation bar issue in iOS 10 with XCode 9? With XCode 9, I have faced header issue in 11 only, NOT in iOS 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44896743/3687801) answer.

Follow these steps:

- Close/Quit Xcode 8 (or any of 8.. series) completely.
- Download Xcode 9 from [Apple site](https://developer.apple.com/download/) (if you have done this already, ignore)

**Step one**

- Right click on the downloaded .dmg file and show package contents
- Navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/`
- Copy the SDKs folder
- Go to older version of Xcode, e.g. Xcode 8, in the `Finder -> Applications -> Xcode`
- Right click and show package contents
- Navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/`
- Paste the copied SDKs folder here

**Step two**

- Right click on the downloaded .dmg file and show package contents
- Navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`
- Copy the `11.0 (15A372)` folder *(Maybe a slight difference, but copy the latest 11.0 (....) folder)*
- Go to older version of Xcode, e.g. Xcode 8, in the `Finder -> Applications -> Xcode`
- Right click and show package contents
- Navigate to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`
- Paste the copied `11.0 (15A372)` folder here *(Maybe a slight difference, but replace the latest 11.0 (....) folder)*

**Finally restart you old Xcode.**