# Is it possible to use Swift 4.0 (4.0.3) with XCode 9.3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9.3

I'm trying to upgrade to XCode 9.3 so that I can run my app on an iOS 11.3 device, but I'm having some issues.

My app has up until this point been built in XCode 9.2 with Swift version 4.0.3. I would like to keep the app on Swift 4.0.3, but I can't seem to choose that option in XCode.

I have toolchains set up to point to: Swift 4.0.3 Release 2017-12-05

When I go to Build Settings -> Swift Language Version I have only three options: Swift 3.3, Swift 4.1, and Unspecified. None of these are working for me.

How can I build and run my app on a device using Swift 4.0?

Comment: Why do you need to keep using Swift 4.0?

Comment: "*None of these are working for me*" – can you please expand on the problem you're facing? Using a Swift 4.0.3 toolchain should work AFAIK.

Comment: Swift 4.1 is backward compatible with 4.0.3.  You should be able to use the new toolchain without making any code changes.

Comment: Try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649266/3687801). Process is the same. Just consider **Xcode 9.2 -> 9.3** instead of 8.x -> 9.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible.

But you can have two different Xcode versions in the Applications folder, just rename one of them.

Comment: I actually do have that. However, the problem is in my 9.2 version I can't debug the app on an 11.3 device. Puts me in a  tough spot.

Comment: That's how it has always been.  There are ways to achieve what you are after.  Look for posts about debugging iOS 10 in Xcode 7.